# Mixed content warnings coming from mediaelement.js swf

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm working on a video player that is running in an https environment and I'm getting mixed content warnings from the mediaelement.js swf, flashmediaelement.swf.

The playback url that I'm using is an https url (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Q2P4LjuVA8), but it seems that the media element swf is ignoring the protocol of the url and making a request to get the http version.

This is the embed tag that gets dropped on the page (notice that the file param in flashVars is https):

```
<embed secure="true" id="me_flash_0" name="me_flash_0" play="true" loop="false" 
       quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" wmode="transparent" allowscriptaccess="always" 
       allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
       pluginspage="//www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
       src="/assets/flashmediaelement.swf"
       flashvars="id=me_flash_0&amp;isvideo=true&amp;autoplay=false&amp;preload=none&amp;width=2844&amp;startvolume=0.8&amp;timerrate=250&amp;flashstreamer=&amp;height=921&amp;file=https://www.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8Q2P4LjuVA8" 
       width="2844" height="921">
```

For reference, I'm running Chrome and using version 2.9.5 of mediaelement.js.

Any ideas as to why I'm getting mixed content warnings in the browser would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: I had similar problem but my problem exists to IE 8 only, On IE9/10 Chrome, Firefox it works without mixed content warning. Even on IE9's Compatability mode it doesn't show warning.